# FNRPE2131090482E - Server is being initialized. Retry the operation

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine, filenet-process-engine, filenet-workplace

I am using Filnet **5.2.1**. I have everything working fine for years.

but suddenly today when trying to connect to process engine from workplace application I am getting the error :

```
[FNRPE2131090482E]Server is being initialized. Retry the operation.
 The Process Engine server is not yet initialized. The software automatically retries your operation but if the problem persists, try again.
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.appserver.PEEngineServlet.<clinit>(PEEngineServlet.java:512)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:189)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1486)
    at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1354)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:623)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:589)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

### Edit

Looking at **pesvr_system.log** I found the following :

```
RPCHandler PEServer.init [Error] FNRPE2131090405E Start up PE server failed; Exception: Unexpected exception -- see chained exception 
     
        at filenet.jpe.general.RuntimeServiceException.ThrowUnchecked(RuntimeServiceException.java:93) 
        at filenet.jpe.rpc.http.HTTPListenerThread.init(HTTPListenerThread.java:144) 
        at filenet.jpe.rpc.main.PEServer.execute(PEServer.java:365) 
        at filenet.jpe.rpc.appserver.PEEngineServlet$ServerStartupThread.run(PEEngineServlet.java:120) 
    PEServer.init [Error] Error starting listening on 9092; Exception: 
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

2021/02/11 11:35:14.937+0300 RPCHandler 7adf27d9 [Info] PEServer: shutting down...
2021/02/11 11:35:14.937+0300 RPCHandler 7adf27d9 [Info] Component Manager.Shutdown...
2021/02/11 11:35:14.937+0300 RPCHandler 7adf27d9 [Info] PEServer: shutting down worker threads..
2021/02/11 11:35:14.953+0300 RPCHandler 7adf27d9 [Info] PEServer:  Finished shutting down.
```

Comment: According to this it may be memory related (out of memory).
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-filenet-composite-platform-installation-tool-52-fails-step-23-28

Comment: my jvm memory are initial 1 g and max 8 g, i updated the question

Comment: Is it possible that the WebSphere did not stop correctly? And have you tried turning the machine off and on again?
Also, you may want to check the documentation for your OS on how to get the information which application is currently listening on Port 9092?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by restoring old backup for filenet GCD database.